# asp.net gridview control retrieve int value cannot implicitly convert type "string" to "int"

Tags: c#, asp.net

I can retrieve the string value from the gridview control cell location, but 
when I try to retrieve an integer value, it tells me "cannot implicitly convert type "string" to "int".

```
public static string vWORKORDER;
public static int vOPERATION_NO;

        vWORKORDER = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[5].Text;
        vOPERATION_NO = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[6].Text;
```

Comment: Text is a string property. There is no automatic conversion of a string to an integer. You need to convert or parse the input (IE search for Convert.ToInt32 or Int.Parse)

Comment: @Steve This is the answer friend, why just a comment?  Don't be modest!

Comment: @Seano666 thanks but there are so many duplicates in the related column that is difficult to choose one

Comment: thanks it worked as you suggested vOPERATION_NO = ToInt32(GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[6].Text); but why would not have something like a object.ValueProperty vs object.Text property?

Comment: @ikask If something like `theCell.ValueProperty`existed, what type it should be? integer? long? decimal? double? What should it return if user writes "abc" in the cell?

Comment: okay good point, thanks.